# How can you filter with custom fields?

Tags: docusignapi

How can you filter with custom fields using DocuSign?

I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are a developer, using the [DocuSign eSignature C# SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/csharp/) and that you want to filter all envelopes based on values of [custom fields](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=qor1583277385137.html&_LANG=enus).

That's a lot that I assume, I also assume you mean custom fields, and not the values of tabs in these envelopes, which is a different thing, but often confused.

The [ListStatusChanges()](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/) API endpoint, also available in the C# SDK can do that.

It has a **custom_field** parameter that you can use.

So, the C# code will look like this:

```
    var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(basePath);
    docuSignClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);

    ListStatusChangesOptions options = new ListStatusChangesOptions();
    options.fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

    options.customField = "myCustomField";

    // Call the API method:
    EnvelopesInformation results = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options);
```